# How to write an expression into a method?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I write the expression into a separate method for optimization:

```js
final listOfKeys= [_firstTabNavKey, _secondTabNavKey, _thirdTabNavKey]

onWillPop: () async {
            return !(await listOfKeys[tabController.index]
                    .currentState
                    ?.maybePop() ??
                false);
          },
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this ?

```
Future<bool> _popBack() async {
   return !(await listOfKeys[tabController.index].currentState?.maybePop() ?? false);
}

onWillPop: _popBack,
```

Comment: Yes. And if I accept a List with keys, how can I pass them into the argument correctly? I added a List with keys to the question

Comment: You want to pass the keys back to another page ?